# classify a table via field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table

I have a dataset of several states and a table with many informations about them, they are already joined, what i want to do now is to create 5 classes about the average lifespan.

they have to be within the ranges of 37 - 50 for class 1, >50 - 60 for class 2, >60 - 70 for class 3, >70 - 75 for class 4 and >75 for class 5.

Now i have already tried the reclass by table tool but for some reason it wont allow me to use the needed fields. when i tried it via properties and then tried to type in 5 classes i couldnt do it as well.

im actually supposed to create a new field and do it by the field calculator in the table but since this field calculator is so different to the selection by attributes im also absolutely lost with that.

Does anybody know a way that might work for my problem?

Comment: [Reclass by Table Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reclass_by_Table/009z000000sq000000/) is for _raster data_. Do your have raster or vector data?

Answer (score 2):

in the field calculator, here is what you can use:

parser : PYTHON

check "show code block"

code block :

```
def reclass(a):

    if (a <= 50):
        return 1
    elif (a <=60):
        return 2
    #add the other conditions here (you must respect the indentation)

    else:
        return 999
```

result :

```
 reclass(!yourfield!)
```

Comment: +1. @Christian: check in which table (_dataset of states_ or _table with informations_) you want to calculate the values​​. Joined table _table with informations_ could be _read only_.

Comment: @Jens: i want to calculate it in the table with informations. how can i check if the table is read only?

Comment: @Christian: It depends on file format of the table. e.g. _text_ and _Excel_ files are read-only. You can edit e.g. _dbf_ and _Geodatabase_ tables. Here is a [list of table formats](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/na/005s00000004000000/).

Comment: @Jens: i think its a geodatabase table and im able to modify it. only problem now is that i used the expressions of radouxju from above but the field calculator wont activate the ok button.i filled in all the informations with intendation in the code block. is there anything that remains to be filled in the field after the =?

Comment: @Christian. You have to calculate the field _before_ you do the join. After the join it is read-only.